# Hiring and firing workers problem (optimization) - quadratic optimization

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces

Suppose we are to set up a special manufacturing company which will operate for only ten months. During the ten months the company is to produce **one million copies** of a single product. We assume that the manufacturing facilities have been leased for the ten-month period, but that labor has not yet been hired. Presumably, employees will be hired and fired during the ten-month period. Our problem is to determine how many employees should be hired or fired in each of the ten months.

It is assumed that each employee produces one **hundred items per month**. The cost of labor is proportional to the number of productive workers, but there is an additional cost due to hiring and firing. If $u(k)$ workers are hired in the $k-th$ month (negative $u(k)$ corresponds to firings), the processing cost can be argued to be $u^2(k)$ because, as $u$ increases, people must be paid to stand in line and more nonproductive employees must be paid. At the end of the ten-month period all workers must be fired. Find $u(k)$ for $k = 1, 2, …, 10$.

**SOLUTION:**  This is my proposition

$u(i)$ = number of workers hired/fired in $i^{th}$ month

$w(k)$ = number of workers in $k^{th}$ month = $\sum_{i=1}^{k} u(t)$

From the problem, 100*$\sum_{k=1}^{10} w(k) = 10^6$ $\iff$  $\sum_{k=1}^{10} (11-k)u(k) = 10^4$

So the minimization problem would be:

minimize  $J =\sum_{k=1}^{11} u^2(k) + \sum_{k=1}^{10} w(k) $

Subject to  $\sum_{k=1}^{11} u(k) = 0 $ and $\sum_{k=1}^{10} (11-k)u(k) = 10^4$

but I am not sure how to get $u(k)$, for each $k = 1, 2,...10 $

Source: (Optimization by vector space methods. Luenberger. Ch3. Prob20)

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that the summations can all be extended to 11 -- you will actually find $x=\begin{bmatrix}u(1) & \cdots & u(11)\end{bmatrix}'$. Second, you have already found that the second term of your objective $J$ is a constant, so it can be dropped. The problem is now equivalent to a least-norm problem in $E^{11}$ (as minimizing $(x\mid x)=x'x$ is equivalent to minimizing $\lVert x\rVert$) subject to $Ax=b$, where $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\ 10 & \cdots & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\10^4\end{bmatrix}$.

Now you get to derive the usual least-norm solution $x=A'(AA')^{-1}b$ from Theorem 3.10.2 (and some linear algebra).

As pointed out above, this $x$ is not an integer solution; with a computer, one can brute-force the rest of the problem (e.g., test the $2^{11}$ integer approximations of $x$ for feasibility and find the one with least norm, though any of these feasible integer approximations turns out to be close to the best in terms of the objective function).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have formulated it, it is a convex quadratic minimization subject to linear constraints. You can solve it using any off the shelf optimization toolbox like cvx.

Comment: I need to solve it analytically, I tried Gram-Schmitdt process but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You can use Lagrange multipliers to solve the continuous version. I just did it but it does not give integer solutions.

Comment: I am not familiar with that method, could you please show that?